# Расшифровка пиктограмм в Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

Не могу найти никакой документации по вопросу, о том, что означают различные значки и пиктограммы в VS2015. Пользуясь отладчиком столкнулся с непонятными обозначениями при проверке свойств модели. Это когда во время отладки можно навести курсором на объект и среда отображает окно с полями объекта и значениями, которые эти поля содержат.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Собственно, что означает гаечный ключ я понял - это доступные свойства, а что за простите "синяя коробка" со "знаком стоп" я так и не понял. Единственное, я не могу получить к ним доступ.

Comment: "Коробка" это Field (поле). Знак стоп - доступ запрещён. Ключ не помню - надо посмотреть, или вложеный класс или свойство. Их же не много. Вложеный класс, поле и свойство.

Comment: Возможно это private-поле?

Comment: Вот тут находится подробное описание всех иконок:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y47ychfe.aspx

Comment: Спасибо. То что нужно.

Comment: Вы тут приняли ответ, состоящий из одной ссылки. По правилам SO в ответе должно быть что-то большее. Именно поэтому на вашем ответе вдвое больше плюсов. ToxyGen почему-то не откликается на просьбу расширить ответ. В результате у меня есть выбор: либо преобразовать его ответ в комментарий (т.е. он будет удалён, галочка снимется, автор потеряет полученную репутацию), либо самостоятельно его дополнить чем-нибудь.

Comment: Но есть ещё один вариант: может быть, вы согласитесь «перенести» свой ответ в ответ ToxyGen? Плюс в том, что сохранится ответ и награда ToxyGen за найденное решение. Минус — вы потеряете ответ и репутацию за 6 плюсов (но это дело наживное). Что вы об этом думаете? Не настаиваю совершенно, правила сайта ничего такого не предписывают.

Comment: Хотел добавить, но ниже уже добавили скриншот. Решил не плодить копипасту.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[image: Основные]

[image: Сигналы]

Добавлю сюда, на всякий случай. Т.е в моем случае, это "запечатанное поле", так Field of variable в первой таблице, и соответствует sealed сигнал из второй.